# How to get Id at Server Side for controls inside PlaceHolder in Asp.Net Web Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, placeholder

I'm working on asp.net web application. I'm dynamically creating controls in one page using placeholder ans user control. inside placeholder there are multiple textboxes.

I'm running this code in a for loop.

```
phSchemaEMITenureDetails.Controls.Add(LoadControl("~/UserControl/SchemaEMITenureDetails.ascx"));
```

means, I want to create multiple sets of these textboxes.

All is working fine, but now I want to get the text data entered by the user in these textboxes at server side. So I need Id of these controls at server side.

I'm not able to get that. Please help me out

User Control:

```
    <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="SchemaEMITenureDetails.ascx.cs" Inherits="PaymentControllerGUI.SchemaEMITenureDetails" %>
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="SchemaRowName"></asp:Label>
<asp:Table runat="server">
    <asp:TableRow runat="server" ID="SchemaEMITenure03MonthRow" Style="display: none;">
        <asp:TableCell>
            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="EMI 03 Months" ID="SchemaEMITenure03MonthLabel">
            </asp:Label>
        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="SchemaEMITenure03MonthTextBox">
</asp:TextBox>
        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>

    <asp:TableRow runat="server" ID="SchemaEMITenure06MonthRow" Style="display: none;">
        <asp:TableCell>
            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="EMI 06 Months" ID="SchemaEMITenure06MonthLabel">
            </asp:Label>
        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TextBox ID="SchemaEMITenure06MonthTextBox" runat="server">
            </asp:TextBox>
        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>

    <asp:TableRow runat="server" ID="SchemaEMITenure09MonthRow" Style="display: none;">
        <asp:TableCell>
            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="EMI 09 Months" ID="SchemaEMITenure09MonthLabel">

            </asp:Label>
        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TextBox ID="SchemaEMITenure09MonthTextBox" runat="server">
            </asp:TextBox>
        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>

    <asp:TableRow runat="server" ID="SchemaEMITenure12MonthRow" Style="display: none;">
        <asp:TableCell>
            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="EMI 12 Months" ID="SchemaEMITenure12MonthLabel">
            </asp:Label>
        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TextBox ID="SchemaEMITenure12MonthTextBox" runat="server">
            </asp:TextBox>
        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>

</asp:Table>
```

Page Aspx:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="phSchemaEMITenureDetails" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Page Aspx.cs: `phSchemaEMITenureDetails.Controls.Add(LoadControl("~/UserControl/SchemaEMITenureDetails.ascx"));`

Answer (score 0):

Update ypur ascx file like this (Just add ID for table)

```
  <asp:Table runat="server" ID="tbl">
        <asp:TableRow runat="server" ID="SchemaEMITenure03MonthRow" Style="display: none;">
            <asp:TableCell>
                <asp:Label runat="server" Text="EMI 03 Months" ID="SchemaEMITenure03MonthLabel">
                </asp:Label>
            </asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="SchemaEMITenure03MonthTextBox">
    </asp:TextBox>....
```

..... 
Now your textbox id is "SchemaEMITenure03MonthTextBox"

You can access this text on aspx as:

```
string value = (tbl.FindControl("SchemaEMITenure03MonthTextBox") as TextBox).Text;
```

> You have to use findcontrol method if your textbox is inside some other
>   control...
>   Just use id of parent control then apply Findcontrol.If your inside more than one parent control then you have to use Findcontrol for multiple time like this

string value = (TopParent.FindControl("InnerParent").FindControl("TextBox") as TextBox).Text;

In this example The textbox is inside of two parent like this

TopParent
   InnerPArent
       Textbox....

Hope It will heplp

Answer (score 0):

You may try going through the controls, and getting the values if the control is a textbox:

```
System.Text.StringBuilder result = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

protected void cmdOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.GetValues(this.phSchemaEMITenureDetails, this.result);
    this.litResult.Text = this.result.ToString();
}

private void GetValues(Control control, System.Text.StringBuilder strBuilder)
{         

    if(control.HasControls())
    {
        foreach (Control item in control.Controls)
        {
            if (item is TextBox)
            {
                TextBox cntrl = (TextBox)item;
                strBuilder.AppendLine(cntrl.ID.ToString() + " = " + cntrl.Text + "<br/>");
            }

            if (item.HasControls())
            {
                this.GetValues(item, strBuilder);
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

I´m pretty sure you can do some improvements in this code. But that's an idea that comes to my mind to solve your problem.